# Transform scale(): Animation on hover fails when the element becomes smaller

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a text rotate 180deg and scale it down when hovering on it (Using transition), however, as the element becomes smaller, it gets out of focus, and the pointer is not anymore over it, and the animation fails.

I'm trying to figure out how to solve this issue but haven't come with a solution yet.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="aligner">
  <div class="titdiv">
    <h1 class="title1">Once upon a time..</h1>   </div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.aligner{
  position: fixed;
  bottom:0px;
  left:0px;
  border:10px solid slateblue; 
  height: 100px;  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color:#fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  width:calc(100% - 20px);
  background-color: #f07d86;
  transition:all 1s linear;
  border-radius:20px;
  transition:1s all;
}

.titdiv:hover{
  color:#333;
  transform:scale(.4) rotate(180deg); 
}
.titdiv{
  transition:1s all
}

.aligner:hover{
  background:#dcdcdc;
  border:1px solid transparent;
  width:100%; 
}
```

Comment: Put an element outside probably of fixed dimensions and on hover rotate the element inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the selector for your CSS rule that has the transform:

```
.aligner:hover .titdiv {...}
```

This is saying, apply the tramsform and color change to the `.titdiv` element when the `.aligner` element is hovered.

```css
.aligner{
  position: fixed;
  bottom:0px;
  left:0px;
  border:10px solid slateblue; 
  height: 100px;  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color:#fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  width:calc(100% - 20px);
  background-color: #f07d86;
  transition:all 1s linear;
  border-radius:20px;
  transition:1s all;
}

.aligner:hover .titdiv{
  color:#333;
  transform:scale(.4) rotate(180deg); 
}
.titdiv{
  transition:1s all
}

.aligner:hover{
  background:#dcdcdc;
  border:1px solid transparent;
  width:100%; 
}
```

```html
<div class="aligner">
  <div class="titdiv">
    <h1 class="title1">Once upon a time..</h1>   </div>
</div>
```